# Как в Unix с помощью shell посчитать число файлов в подкаталоге?

Tags: unix, shell

Как в Unix с помощью shell посчитать число файлов в подкаталоге?

Comment: `find ./dir -type f | wc -l`?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, как вы понимаете фразу - _с помощью shell_?

Comment: @0xdb, возможно автор просто имел ввиду работу в терминале? Лучше конечно было бы уточнить какой именно shell используется - bash / ksh / zsh /  tcsh / etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так только в указанном подкаталоге текущего каталога:

```
$ find ./subdir -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
ls -dl Music/*|grep "^[-]"|wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
find / -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -printf '%h\n' | uniq -c
```

Количество файлов и папок в каждом каталоге, вывод будет выглядеть так:

```
 ...
  115 /etc
  5 /opt
  1 /media
 ...
```

Возможно указание параметра `-type` для поиска только файлов `f` или директорий `d`

---

Для поиска в одном подкаталоге уже был дан ответ.